# importing an external Class and creating an object , accessing the functions of the object

Tags: python, object, inheritance, import, external

In my Main.py
I have put

```
from carNum import *
vehicleID =0
vehicleID = carNum()
print ("Object Created")
```

Here is my carNum class

```
class carNum:
   def __init__(self):
      speedlist = []
```

But when I run this I am getting 'module' object is not callable

Thank you very much in advance 
I really hope you guys can help me out

Comment: Is your `carNum` class in a file called `carNum.py`? For me it gives error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'instance' and 'int'` for line `vehicleID= vehicleID + 1`. I fail to see what this question has to do with inheritance.

Comment: speedlist is going to be a variable local to the constructor only.  If you want such attribute to belong to the class or to the object instances then stop and improve your knowledge of python now. It would save you pain down the road.

Comment: @Pynchia Thank you for the advice. I am a beginner still. even if I make that List global , when I try to call the list through the created object it is giving me an error saying " global name speedlist is not defined" could you please tell me if you have any suggestions

Comment: I can also suggest you should get familiar with PEP-0008 (Python coding conventions). Modules and variables should be named in lowercase, words splitted with underscores: ```car_num```, ```vehicle_id```. Classes should be named in CamelCase with leading letter in uppercase: ```CarNum```.

Comment: no worries, we have all started from nil. If you google "python namespaces tutorial" you will find plenty of interesting resources worth reading.

Comment: As far as SO is concerned, I recommend you describe what you want to achieve. Otherwise you fall into the classic XY problem (i.e. describing your solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**import** can used to import modules, that may contain classes as well functions and other stuff, and not only to import classes.
In python you can put multiple classes in the same file, as well as the *main program*. For example you can put in your main.py (which is your module), the following:

```
class carNum(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # initialize some attribute
        self.speedlist = []

myobject = carNum()
Print("Object Created")
```

I left out this part:

```
vehicleID =0
vehicleID = carNum()
vehicleID = vehicleID + 1
```

since to me it doesn't make any sense.

You can also put the **cardNum** class into a separate module (i.e: *cardnum.py*) and then import it in your main module (i.e: *main.py*) using:

```
from cardnum import cardNum
```

Comment: Thanks @daniele For the reply, but I can not use the carNum class inside Main.py. So when I use from carNum import carNum im getting an import error  " can not import name carNum

Comment: I have saved the file as carNum.py

Comment: Does your `carNum.py` also import from `main.py`?

Comment: Can you please highlight your project structure better?